# Find the value of the series given the nth term

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n}=2^{-n}$ and $b_{n}=\frac{4}{4n^2+4n-3}$. I want to find the value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}$ from where

$$cn=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}b_{n-k}$$ I feel that the first thing I can do is simplify the above, so for that try the following

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k} b_{n-k}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2^{-k}}{n^2-2nk+k^2+nk-k-\frac{3}{4}}\right)$$

The latter as a result of replacing values in the terms of $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ that were originally given. But I am really stuck, what can I do after that? any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Looks like $\sum c_n= \big(\sum a_n\big)\big(\sum b_n\big)$, that product is definitely simpler. Try proving above identity, positive terms will allow rearranging summands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of [Cauchy product and Mertens' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), which states that if the series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n}$ converges to $A$ and
$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }b_{n}$ converges to $B$, and at least one of them converges absolutely, then their Cauchy product $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }c_n=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}b_{n-k}$ converges to $AB$.

We have $A=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a_{n}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }2^{-n}=2$, which converges absolutely.

$$B=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }b_{n}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{4}{4n^2+4n-3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{2n + 3}\right)=\\(-1-\frac{1}{3})+(1-\frac{1}{5})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{7})+(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{9})+(\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{11})+(\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{13})+\cdots=0$$
Therefore, $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }c_n=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}b_{n-k}$ converges to $AB=0$.